# How to compare 2 Enterprise Architecture projects .eap?

Tags: enterprise-architect, rtc

I am using Enterprise Architecture (EA)12. I came across the situation where I want to compare the projects. 
Can we create a baseline for EA, do we have the option to compare the EA projects?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For full model compare try `Project|Data Management...|Project Compare`

You can compare .eap files or DBMS models.

You can also compare a single package against either a saved baseline, a saved xmi file, or a version of the package (xmi file) in your version control system.